# Multithreading for loops in Swift 4

Tags: swift, multithreading, loops, swift4, grand-central-dispatch

I need a bit of help on proper for loop multithreading for swift 4. Should I use a normal dispatch queue or should I use concurrent threading? Or am I thinking about this wrong? The specific instance I am looking at here is: say we want to do something to a list of objects, such as retrieve a user picture from a database for all users that are missing one in a local database on the device.

```
let utilityQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.company.utility", qos: .utility)
for i in 1 ... 10000 {
    utilityQueue.async {
        getMissingImage(user[i])
    }
}
```

The above seems to work for me, but I found another option in my reading, but using concurrency such as below

```
let concurrentQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.company.concurrent", attribute: .concurrent)
for i in 1 ... 10000 {
    concurrentQueue.async {
        getMissingImage(user[i])
    }
}
```

Which is correct or is there a better way to handle this that I am missing?

Comment: What is ThreadManager? Any approach involving "I am spawning a thread" is incorrect. There are no cases in Swift where you should be spawning a thread. I suspect you don't really mean that, though. GCD is not a thread-management system. It's a queue-management system. Those are not the same things.

Comment: Also, what are "concurrentThread" and "utilityThread" in your question. They look like queues, not threads. In that case, the answer depends completely on how their defined.

Comment: The comment above thread manager is the actual return of the call. it creates a dispatch queue with QOS of .utility in this instance. Basically, I want to speed up for loops that could end up running for large amounts of records by throwing them out to multiple threads. I don't want the loop to run one at a time in order for 1k runs, I want it to run on, for instance, 8 threads at once.

Comment: The concurrent thread (now renamed to concurrentQueue) and utility version are short sudo representations of a dispatch queue with .concurrent attribute and a normal .utility qos dispatch

Comment: Threads themselves are generally the solution to these kinds of problems. There is a lot of code in your question that is not shown, and is the whole point of the question. A serial queue will process its dispatched blocks in order. A concurrent queue *may* process its dispatched blocks in parallel (but it may not, depending on many things). What is the simplest version of your loop, with no fancy threads/queues/etc? And where is the bottleneck in that version? Network requests are about the slowest thing you can possibly do, so that's the heart of this question.

Comment: So I modified the question to try and clean it up and drop it down to the core question: What is the proper way to mutithread the for loop. I have seen it done a number of ways so what exactly is the best practice? I dropped my real code in favor of conceptual code that should get the point across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attempt to start an unconstrained number of concurrent tasks, is dangerous, because GCD has a very limited number of worker threads and if you exhaust them, you can adversely impact other operations within the app.

So consider your example:

```
let concurrentQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.company.concurrent", attributes: .concurrent)
for i in 0 ..< 10_000 {
    concurrentQueue.async {
        self.getMissingImage(self.user[i])
    }
}
```

You might use `OperationQueue` which lets you easily constrain the degree of concurrency, in this example not more than 4 at a time:

```
let queue = OperationQueue()
queue.name = "com.company.concurrent"
queue.qualityOfService = .userInitiated
queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 4

for i in 0 ..< 10_000 {
    queue.addOperation {
        self.getMissingImage(self.user[i])
    }
}
```

You can accomplish something similar with GCD semaphores, but it’s a little more fragile and I’d suggest the above.

Note, this assumes that `getMissingImage` runs synchronously (i.e. will not return until the task is completely done). If not, you’ll have to pursue other patterns.

Comment: So what would be the ideal operations count for something that you want done in a timely manner? For instance, something you would normally push to a userInitiated qos queue.

Comment: Regarding “ideal” `maxConcurrentOperationCount` if it’s wrapping network requests, 4-6 are good values. If you want `userInitiated` qos, you can explicitly set `qualityOfService` property of the operation queue, too.